# Getting New Users and Returning Users breakdown (new payers vs returning payers)

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to get the new users versus returning users breakdown by if these users are payers or not, in SQL. ( see picture attached for more info on what i am trying to achieve.

So, the initial dataset is this:

```
Initial Dataset:

date    client ID   Purchase Value  Product Category
2-Jan   001  $2.00  cereals
2-Jan   002  $3.00  cereals
3-Jan   001  $1.00  cereals
4-Jan   003  $-     bread
5-Jan   002  $3.00  cereals
5-Jan   003  $-     bread
5-Jan   005  $-     cereals
```

Aiming to get this dataset:

Final Dataset Columns
[final_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MxiZ.png)

Following this approach attached in the image: 
[Final dataset approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AoTP.png)

Would anyone be able to advise what is the best approach to tackle the query in SQL to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

[Final Dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfmJw.png)

Comment: Please provide desired results *as a text table* in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, added the desired results in the final dataset image inserted in the question. thank you